# How to keep a .NET Socket object connection open after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, postback

I am working on an ASP.NET site where it is required that a single Socket be created and kept connected across all pages for the current session. I have created and stored the socket as a session object and it remains connected after a page redirect, but the connection is closed whenever a postback occurs (such as a button click). Is there any way to keep the socket connection open even after a postback, as the requirement is that a single connection be used for the entire session and reconnecting the socket is not an option.

Comment: Show us your code. Postbacks do not close sockets. What is this socket used for?

Comment: The connection you are talking about: do you mean the one between the browser and the web-server, or is this connection between the web-server and some unmentioned 3rd place?

Comment: @MarcGravell - The connection is between the web-server and another server from where some data will be transferred through the socket.

Comment: @user1687951 I should ask: is it really necessary to have a socket per session? that doesn't sound very scaleable. If you control that socket at both ends, I would **strongly** suggest using some kind of multiplexer that allows you to share it between sessions. As an example, here on SO we make *quite considerable* use of redis: however, each app-domain has only a *single* (yes: single) socket to the server. We just share it... *a lot*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session-state is brittle; in fact, what you describe won't even work if you are using a serializing session-state provider (a socket is not serializable).

So: rather than storing the *socket* in session, put the socket somewhere else - maybe a synchronized dictionary - and store just a *key* to it in session. For example:

```
public static class SocketStore
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Socket> socketStore
          = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
    public static string Add(Socket socket)
    {
        if(socket == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");
        string newKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        lock(socketStore) {
            socketStore.Add(newKey, socket);
        }
        return newKey;
    }
    public static Socket Get(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        Socket result;
        lock (socketStore)
        {
            if (!socketStore.TryGetValue(key, out result)) result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In usage, if you don't have a socket (/key) already, create your connection, store it with `Add`, and then store the key in session. When fetching, you must handle the `null` case, and you will also want to add your own synchronization, to guard against the same socket being used by two concurrent requests from the same session (perfectly legal).

However, as additional notes:

- you will want to have some additional process to clean down old sockets from abandoned sessions, and zombie-sockets from healthy-looking sessions
- you will need requests to keep coming back to the same server - so "sticky" load-balancing if you are in a cluster

Comment: Thanks, this works for keeping the socket connected, but I have another problem. After sending one packet of data, I am not able to send another. Is there some default waiting period between sending data or do I need to release any resources first?

Comment: @user1687951 which API are you using to send (there are at least 3 just on `Socket`)? Also: what *happens*? does it throw an exception? if so: what exception? does it block? what?

Comment: I am using the Send(byte[] buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags) method of the System.Net.Socket class. Its getting blocked and I'm not getting any exception. Here's the code:                              public string send(string data)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data + "\r\n");
      
        int byteCount = socket.Send(buffer, SocketFlags.None); }

Comment: @user1687951 you say you are getting blocked; what *exactly* happens? and have you seen all the clarifications at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145160.aspx ?

Comment: oops, looks like there was a problem with the data I was sending. Thanks a lot for your patience and help. :)